# How do the 4.x/5.x Linux kernel and udev expose button-press events on Bluetooth headsets?

Tags: bluetooth, linux-kernel, bluetooth-lowenergy, linux-device-driver, udev

I have a Plantronics M70 Bluetooth headset that, like most headsets, includes a "feature" button.  When connected to a smartphone, this is usually used to initiate a call.  I want to use it to initiate a brief audio recording, such as taking a memo.  Is there a way to create a udev rule that will tie the button press event to a script?  The headset will generate a double-beep if the button is held down longer; can that be used to trigger a second feature?

I can observe Wireshark traffic when the button is pressed while the device is in use as an A2DP high-fidelity audio sink, but I cannot get "udevadm monitor" to observe the event.

Suggestions, engineering?

Comment: Can you try running "btmon" and observe if you see HCI events triggered when you press the button? You can also see if there's a difference between a short press and a long press in terms of HCI messages sent.

Comment: Are you able to find any bluetooth related input devices under `/dev/input` ?